# Parse Address using Regex Capture Groups

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-group

I am trying to parsing the addresses into groups and I have this regular expression:

```
(^.*?(?:Lane|Street|Boulevard|Crescent|Place|Road|Highway|Avenue|Drive|Circuit|Parade|Telopea|Nicklin Way|Terrace|Square|Court|Close|Endeavour Way|Esplanade|East|The Centreway|Mall|Quay|Gateway|Low Way|Point|Rd|Morinda|Way|Ave|St|South Steyne|Broadway|HQ|Expressway|Street|Castlereagh|Meadow Way|Track|Kulkyne Way|Narabang Way|Bank)),(?:)? ?(.*?),? ?([A-Z]{2,3}),? ?(\d{,4})$
```

which is capturing and group these addresses:

```
139 McKinnon Road, PINELANDS, NT, 829
108 East Point Road, Fannie Bay, NT, 820
3-11 Hamilton Street, Townsville City, QLD, 4810
40 17 Geranium Street, THE GARDENS, NT, 820
Lot 9 Island Point Road, ST GEORGES BASIN, NSW, 2540
316 Sturt Street and 511 Flinders Street, Townsville City, QLD, 4810
```

but not capturing addresses with these format:

```
1, 3, 5 Demeter Street & 12 Hermes Avenue ROUSE HILL NSW 2155
31 Stephen Street SOUTH TOOWOOMBA QLD 4350
```

I would like to have these addresses into separate groups like:

```
street_address = 1, 3, 5 Demeter Street & 12 Hermes Avenue
subrub = ROUSE HILL
state = QLD
postcode = 4350
```

How to capture both the addresses using the above expression? Here is my [Regex code](https://regex101.com/r/vfAcrp/1)

Comment: I'd try `^([0-9\- ,]*[^,]+ +(Lane|Street|Boulevard|Crescent|Place|Road|Highway|Avenue|Drive|Circuit|Parade|Telopea|Nicklin Way|Terrace|Square|Court|Close|Endeavour Way|Esplanade|East|The Centreway|Mall|Quay|Gateway|Low Way|Point|Rd|Morinda|Way|Ave|St|South Steyne|Broadway|HQ|Expressway|Street|Castlereagh|Meadow Way|Track|Kulkyne Way|Narabang Way|Bank)),? +(.*?),? +([A-Z]{2,3}),? +(\d{1,4})$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use specific regex to match each of your four groups separately using the following ones:

- **Group 1**, containing the address, called `<street_address>`:

```
.*(?:Lane|Street|Boulevard|Crescent|Place|Road|Highway|Avenue|Drive|Circuit|Parade|Telopea|Nicklin Way|Terrace|Square|Court|Close|Endeavour Way|Esplanade|East|The Centreway|Mall|Quay|Gateway|Low Way|Point|Rd|Morinda|Way|Ave|St|South Steyne|Broadway|HQ|Expressway|Street|Castlereagh|Meadow Way|Track|Kulkyne Way|Narabang Way|Bank)
```

- **Group 2**, containing the subrub, called `<subrub>`:

```
[A-Za-z ]+
```

- **Group 3**, containing the state, called `<state>`:

```
[A-Z]+
```

- **Group 4**, containing the postcode, called :

```
\d+
```

---

Your **final regex** is none other than the concatenation of these regex using an optional comma and a mandatory space `,?` .

```
(?P<street_address>.*(?:Lane|Street|Boulevard|Crescent|Place|Road|Highway|Avenue|Drive|Circuit|Parade|Telopea|Nicklin Way|Terrace|Square|Court|Close|Endeavour Way|Esplanade|East|The Centreway|Mall|Quay|Gateway|Low Way|Point|Rd|Morinda|Way|Ave|St|South Steyne|Broadway|HQ|Expressway|Street|Castlereagh|Meadow Way|Track|Kulkyne Way|Narabang Way|Bank)),? (?P<subrub>[A-Za-z ]+),? (?P<state>[A-Z]+),? (?P<postcode>\d+)
```

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Dymtjh/1).

*Note*: In your Python code, you'll be able to extract each group by its corresponding name.